# Logging each request to a separate json file with RestRserve

Tags: r, restrserve

How would one set up logging each request to a different json file with `RestRserve`?

I tried using the `lgr` package (referred to in [RestRserve's doc on logging](https://restrserve.org/articles/Logging.html)) like so:

```
library(RestRserve)
library(lgr)

app = Application$new(content_type = "text/plain")

# RestRserve logger
app$logger = RestRserve::Logger$new(level = "trace", name = "mylogger",
  printer=function(timestamp, level, logger_name, pid, message, ...)
  {
    lgr$log(level=tolower(level), msg=message, ...)
  }
)

# JSON appender in lgr
tf <- tempfile(tmpdir="D:/temp", fileext=".log")
lgr$add_appender(AppenderJson$new(tf), name = "json")

# Endpoint
app$add_get("/sqrt", function(request, response) {
  on.exit({
    # Next log file
    tf <- tempfile(tmpdir="D:/temp", fileext=".log")
    lgr$appenders$json$set_file(tf)
  })
  app$logger$info(msg="", context=list(request_id = request$id, message="Process start"))
  response$body = sqrt(x)
  app$logger$info(msg="", context=list(request_id = request$id, message="Process end"))
})

# Submit request
request = Request$new(path = "/sqrt", method = "GET", parameters_query = list(x = "10"))
response = app$process_request(request)
```

But this splits up a request's log info across two files. I'm also quite sure it wouldn't work for simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you even don't need any special logger - just use `writeLines`. Also you can rely on `req$id` to name files since it is unique.

```
library(RestRserve)

req = Request$new()
res = Response$new()

fl = file.path(tempdir(), paste0(req$id, ".log"))
con = file(fl, open = "at")
writeLines("Process start", con)
res$set_body(sqrt(10))
writeLines("Process end", con)
close(con)

readLines(fl)
unlink(fl)
```